# QMdiSubWindow. Как узнать, открыто ли окно?

Tags: qt

Добрый день.
Есть `MDI`-приложение. При нажатии пунктов меню открываются `QMdiSubWindow`'ы. Нужно, чтобы при наличии уже открытого внутреннего окна, такое же не открывалось при повторном нажатии на тот же пункт меню.
Пока решаю эту проблему проверкой параметра `WindowTitle` в каждом объекте списка из метода `mdiArea->subWindowList()` на совпадение (чтобы не было двух одинаковых). Но этот метод выглядит больно уж костыльно. Наверняка есть способ поэлегантнее. Прошу знатоков подсказать.
Спасибо.
ЗЫ Вот до такого способа дошёл, имеет право на существование?:

```
void MainWindow::CatProducts_open()
{
    CatProducts *buf = QObject::findChild<CatProducts*>("catProducts");
    if(buf==0)
    {
        CatProducts *catProducts = new CatProducts;
        catProducts->setObjectName("catProducts");
        mdiArea->addSubWindow(catProducts);
        catProducts->show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Наверняка есть способ поэлегантнее

Создаваемые `QMdiSubWindow`'ы наследуют `QWidget`, котрый, в свою очередь наследует `QObject`. У последнего есть два замечательных метода [`QObject::setProperty`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#setProperty) и [`QObject::property`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#property). Первым методом мы можем присвоить какое-то свойство (именованное значение), вторым - считать его.

Таким образом, создавая очередное окно - нужно его обозначить этим самым свойством. Далее, по списку окон его по этому свойству несложно найти.

Плюс этого подхода таков, что значение свойств мы вправе делать уникальными (а так и надо), а вот заголовки окон могут быть неуникальными. Поэтому поиск по свойствам - простое и верное решение.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Собственно, это то же, что и я хотел сделать, только грамотнее (согласен с доводом про уникальность).

Comment: А вот сейчас я нашёл вариант через setObjectName() и последующий findChild<>(). Вот только не пойму, как это реализовать.

Comment: В случае с setPropery/property вы сможете "идентифицировать" окна простыми целыми числами. А в случае setObjectName - придется "изобретать" строки. А оно вам надо?

Comment: Разве идентифицировать окна цифрами информативно?

Comment: Идентификация == нахождение нужного. Уникальной цифры достаточно. Другой вопрос "что и как делать с окнами?" Тут можно хранить хэш указателей (ключ хэша => та самая цифра). Остальную инфу можно извлекать по указателям.

Answer (score 1):

Если для создания окна используется сигнал от `QAction` (что обычно так и есть), то, как вариант, можно обыграть на переключении слотов:

```
void MainWindow::CatProducts_open() {
    QAction *action = qobject_cast<QAction*>(sender());
    if(action == Q_NULLPTR) return;

    // Отключаем "action" от текущего слота.
    // Если используется иной сигнал, то соответствующим
    // образом правим строку ниже.
    disconnect(action, &QAction::triggered
        , this, &MainWindow::CatProducts_open);

    CatProducts *catProducts = new CatProducts;
    catProducts->setObjectName("catProducts");
    mdiArea->addSubWindow(catProducts);
    catProducts->show();

    connect(action, &QAction::triggered
        , catProducts, &CatProducts::show);
}
```

Comment: Тоже вариант. Спасибо.